# I was trying to create a discord bot and i got this error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Client')"

Tags: javascript

The code is

```
const {Discord} = require('discord.js');

const {client} = new Discord.Client();

console.log(client)

client.once('ready', (stream) => {
    console.log('Gabor Haladit is online');
});



client.login('OTIyMjU2MTgyMzYwNTUxNDc0.Yb-0AA.obEDZ6QR2imMcZHCyT45sa7b53E');
```

If you see any other wrong things please telle me! Thanks

Comment: Did you really just put your discord bot token publicly on Stack Overflow?

Comment: I don't use Discord, but the error is saying discord is undefined, so does your require want to be `const Discord = require('discord.js')`